# combination of heuristic and cost based approach in Query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying hard to understand How can these cost estimation techniques be combined with the heuristic rules during query optimization by the DBMS and the effect this has on reducing the workload of a Database? Someone who knows kindly explain. Thanks

Comment: The subject of query optimization is very broad.  I would start with the documentation for the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am using MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the "cost-based optimization" usually comes up with the same results as some good heuristics.  Here are some of my heuristics:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql  It includes discussions into now to peek into `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON`, Optimizer trace, and Handler counts.

The Optimizer uses the costs, not heuristics.  I use my heuristics, not costs, except for what the Handlers give me.